# Continuity on kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\{A_k\}_{k\in{\mathbb{N}}}$ a sequence of $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose that $A_k \to A$, and consider $B$ another $n\times n$ matrix. Its true that...

$A_k \otimes B \to A \otimes B$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because the Kronecker product is a function $M(n,m)\times M(n,m)\rightarrow M(n,m)$ that is componentwise continuous.

**Added**: "Componentwise continuous" means that sending $(A,B)\mapsto (A\otimes B)_{ij}$ is continuous $\forall i,j$